# Tilde "~" expression not functioning in "R"?

Tags: r, tilde-expansion

The tilde expression is not working on my RStudio! I am using a windows 10 OS.

Update : After looking more carefully(thanks to Dason) It seems the "~" is pointing to "user/Documents/" rather then "user/". is there any work around?

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure "~" points where you think it points?

Comment: Also never post an image when you can post the actual code/results.

Comment: Ideally it should point to home directory, shouldn't it?
Ok Thanks, I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: Dear Dason, Yes it's actually pointing to a different folder the "documents" folder. How can I rectify that?

Comment: You've not shown a single call with `~` working. What does `setwd("~/")` do? Then what does `getwd()` say after that? How do you assume it points to `user/Documents`?

Comment: no one mentioned `path.expand('~')` yet?

Comment: Hello spacedman, actually I  'setwd("~/")' is working fine and 'getwd()' showing the path of documents folder. That's how I got to know the actual point of '~'.

Comment: Also `normalizePath("~")`, which really just runs `path.expand` here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The home directory in Windows R is set using the environment variable `R_USER` Set this using Windows (search from the Start Menu for "environment variable"). Whatever you set this to will become what R uses for `~`. I have mine set to `C:\Users\trehman\R`.

Here is how mine looks.

[image]

Comment: Thanks TARehman, Looks like a promising solution, will let you know after trying it. Thanks again for you time N help.

Comment: i added [~] to both user and system environment with value [C:/users/user/] but still no change can you guide me with a bit elaboration.

Comment: @Mrinal9 Does it look like mine?

Comment: No actually there is no R_user variable in my Environment variable. I had added [~] as a variable with a value to my home folder. Let me try like yours & see.

Comment: Yep! Now its working fine. Thanks a ton again for the generous help sir.

Comment: On Windows you can set either `R_USER` or `HOME` with priority given to `R_USER`. A bit more information here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f

Answer (score 2):

As you found out yourself, R's `~` points to your documents folder. An easy way to work around this could be to start the paths you want to reference with `~/../`. So your `setwd` call would look like this:

```
setwd('~/../{your actual path from home}')
```

The same problem occurs on my Windows PC. I do not have a Linux machine at hand to test whether it is the same there. R gets this variable from the `R_USER` environment variable. You can override that in your R environment startup file. This issue is not specific to RStudio and also occurs when you start an R session from the command line.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help, but can you tell me why its not working? or it does not work in any windows system?

Comment: @Mrinal9, I added some extra info. I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please add a little bit info on how to & what to edit to R environment startup file?
Thanks,
Mrinal.

Answer (score 0):

At startup, R looks for `Renviron.site` in the `R_HOME` directory. Open and edit it

`file.edit(file.path(Sys.getenv('R_HOME'), 'etc', 'Renviron.site'))`

Define `R_USER` in that file with the path you want `'~'` to point to:

`R_USER = 'C:/Users/USERNAME'`

References:
[R for Enterprise: Understanding R’s Startup](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/)