# Read() function in R is looking at wrong folder

Tags: r

When I'm calling any read.___() function in R it is looking at the wrong file path. I have tried changing the working directory multiple times and it keeps going to the same path. For example I'm trying the following:

```
setwd("C:/OneDrive/")
read.csv("~/Desktop/Data/file.csv")
```

I then get the following error:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
> Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
> 'C:/OneDrive/Documents/Desktop/Data/file.csv': No such file
> or directory

For some reason the read() function adds the documents folder in place of the specified working directory. I tried uninstalling and deleting all files related to R on my computer then reinstalling. I still get the same issue. I've seen others ask a similar question, but everyone keeps telling them to set the working directory to something different. It doesn't matter what I set the working directory to. R keeps adding the Documents folder into the path. How do I get it to stop adding the Documents folder?

Comment: Using `~` is just a shorthand for absolute path to environment path variable. See [Tilde "~" expression not functioning in "R"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34400903/1422451)

Comment: See what `path.expand("~/Desktop/Data/file.csv")` gives. It's probably that filename.